# How to connect a Windows laptop to an Ubuntu laptop

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking

I learned from ehow.com about [How to Direct Connect a Windows laptop to an Ubuntu Laptop](http://www.ehow.com/how_6761910_direct-windows-pc-ubuntu-laptop.html), quoted as follows:

> 1. Power on both computers.
> 2. Plug the crossover cable into each computer's respective ethernet port.
> 3. Set the Windows computer to use a static IP address.
> 4. Set the Linux computer to use a static IP address. The two computers
>    should now be able to communicate.

I was wondering:

1. How to set up to use a  static IP address in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 8.10 with WICD?
2. When finishing the four steps, what softwares to run on the two computers for them to see each other and transfer files from/to each other?
3. If the same method applies to any two OSes? For example, Windows and Windows, Ubuntu and Ubuntu?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I agree with @Kyle, Samba is probably the easiest way to go. If you want to set a static IP in Ubuntu just open a Terminal and type `ifconfig`. Find the port for your wireless or ethernet LAN that you're using (usually `eth0` or `wlan0`) then type `ifconfig eth0 <static-ip-here>` replacing `<static-ip-here>` with something like `192.168.0.50`

Answer (score 1):

IF the computers are already on the same network you can skip the whole top part and just install Samba. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605) is the guide from the Ubuntu forums, this is a fairly simple method of sharing files between the two OS's.